# How to force an url to be open in the device's browser when my app is set as the default app to open this url

Tags: android, android-intent

I set my android app to open certain urls from a specific server.
A situation may occur when my app is not meant to open a certain url, and so the server will return an error.

Once an error received, I would like to open this url in the device's browser.
Since my app was set as the default app to open this kind of urls, trying to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, URI);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Will cause the app to open recursively and endlessly since the device is recognizing the url as a url that needs to be open by my app.

One solution that I found is forcing the device to open the url in chrome:`intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");`

A problem arises if the device does not contain the chrome app.

Is there an elegant solution rather then listing all the possible android browsers one by one?

**P.S.** the problematic urls do not have a common prefix that can distinguish them from the others.

Comment: You could use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`, on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for some URL that you own that is not picked up by your `<intent-filter>`. Use that to identify a browser that you can then use via `setPackage()`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) suggested, I used PackageManger's queryIntentActivities() method to find the default browser:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, unusedURI);
List<ResolveInfo> l = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

To extract the process name I used: `l.get(0).activityInfo.processName`:

```
intent.setPackage(l.get(0).activityInfo.processName);
```

Notice that it is also possible to receive all the matching apps by using the flag `PackageManager.MATCH_ALL`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use the `ResolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName`?